# Resize and Rename Image in Django UpdateView

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to be able to create 3 different sizes of an image when a user uploads an image in an UpdateView in Django.

I also want to be able to rename the file they upload to something like username_thumb_01.jpg, username_original_01.jpg, username_medium_01.jpg.

#### views.py

```
class UserProfileEditView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = UserProfileForm
    template_name = "edit_profile.html"
```

#### forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

#### models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)  
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="user-photos", null=True, blank=True)
```

I tried to add something like the following to my UserProfileEditView but it didnt work and I wasnt sure If i was on the right track.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if self.request.files:
          filename= join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, profile.avatar.name)
          im = Image.open(filename)
          im.thumbnail((160,160), Image.ANTIALIAS)
          im.save(imfn, "JPEG")
          form.save
```

Has anyone done this before? How can I accomplish it ?

Comment: It's usually good to upvote an answer as well as accept it. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this by using a custom image field.  The code for it is available on github at https://github.com/hellsgate1001/django-thumbs.

I didn't create this, I forked it to add a bit more flexibility to the thumbnail creation and also to ensure it works with Django 1.5

Answer (score 2):

Although their approach is different I suggest using [sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail). Instead of creating the images when they are uploaded what this does is creates them when they are required and then caches them using whatever caching system you specify.